# I can't redownload Skyrim on my Xbox

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

So I accidently deleted Skyrim off of it. I originally put the skyrim code for the game on my other account but I deleted the account. The game worked on my new account also but now I deleted it and can't get it back. Looked on download history and searched the game and I have to buy it.

Comment: Can't you redownload it from your other account?

Comment: You probably can't re-download it because you deleted the account it was licensed to, so there isn't anyone who owns the game on your console, so you can't re download it.

Comment: recovering your old gamertag and using that is likely the only option.

Answer (score 2):

Ownership of a digital game is tied to the account. If there is no account on a console that owns the game, you can't download it- there's essentially no difference between you and someone who has never bought Skyrim in their life.

Your only options at this stage are either recovering the old account or buying a new copy of Skyrim.